# NameError when calling function

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have to write a program that has the user input stock information, calculate some variables, and spit it back out in a while loop. I keep getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'bc' is not defined
```

for the line

```
amt_paidcomm_onpurch,sold_for,comm_onsale,profit_loss = calc(shares,pp,sp,bc)
```

Here is the code:

```
 def load():
    shares = int(input("Enter Number of shares: "))
    pp = float(input("Enter Purchase price: "))
    sp = float(input("Enter selling price: "))
    bc = float(input("Enter Commission: "))
    print("\n")

    return shares, pp, sp, bc

def calc(shares,pp,sp,bc):
    amt_paid = shares * pp
    comm_onpurch  = amt_paid * bc
    sold_for = shares * sp
    comm_onsale = sold_for * bc
    profit_loss = (sold_for - comm_onsale) - (amt_paid + comm_onpurch)

    return amt_paid, comm_onpurch, sold_for,comm_onsale,profit_loss

def output(name, amt_paid, comm_onpurch, sold_for,comm_onsale,profit_loss):
    print("Stock Name: ", name, "\n")
    print("Amount paid for the stock: $", format(amt_paid, ',.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on purchase: $", format(comm_onpurch, ',.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for: $", format(sold_for, ',.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale: $", format(comm_onsale, ',.2f'))
    print("Profit or loss (if negative): $", format(profit_loss, ',.2f'))
    print('\n')

def main():
    total=0.0
    name=input('Enter stock name or -999 to quit: ')
    while name != '-999':
        shares,pp,sp,rate=load()
        amt_paidcomm_onpurch,sold_for,comm_onsale,profit_loss = calc(shares,pp,sp,bc)
        output(name,amt_paid,comm_onpurch,sold_for,comm_onsale,profit_loss)
        total=total+profit_loss
        name=input("Enter stock name or -999 to quitz: ")
    print(total)
main()
```

Thank you!!

Comment: What do you think that name should be?

Comment: `shares,pp,sp,**rate**=load()`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `load()` you assign the variable `bc` to the name `rate`. So either assign it to the name `bc` or change your calling of the `calc` function to use `rate` instead.

i.e. At the moment you have:

```
    shares,pp,sp,rate=load()
    amt_paidcomm_onpurch,sold_for,comm_onsale,profit_loss = calc(shares,pp,sp,bc)
```

But you want something like:

```
    shares,pp,sp,bc=load()
    amt_paidcomm_onpurch,sold_for,comm_onsale,profit_loss = calc(shares,pp,sp,bc)
```

or:

```
    shares,pp,sp,rate=load()
    amt_paidcomm_onpurch,sold_for,comm_onsale,profit_loss = calc(shares,pp,sp,rate)
```

Comment: I totally missed that!! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem - good luck with the project :) could you [mark your question as answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?